# Fortran final routine calls itself before variable goes out of scope

Tags: fortran, destructor, final, intel-fortran

I have a problem with Fortran destructors/final routines.
Having the code below:

```
  module my_type_module
    implicit none

    type my_type
      contains
        final :: destructor
    end type my_type

    interface my_type
      ! Constructor declaration
      module procedure my_type_constructor
    end interface my_type

    contains
      function my_type_constructor()
        type(my_type) :: my_type_constructor

        print *, 'In constructor address is: ',
 &          loc(my_type_constructor)

      end function my_type_constructor

      subroutine destructor(this)
        type(my_type) :: this
        print *, 'Destructor of my_type object with address: ',
 &        loc(this)
      end subroutine destructor

  end module my_type_module

  program trial

    use my_type_module
    implicit none

    type(my_type) :: argument

    print *, 'Trial program starts'
    print *, 'Initial address is', loc(argument)

    argument = my_type_constructor()

    print *, 'Address afer constructor is called is', loc(argument)

    print *, 'doing some work...'
    print *, 'finishing program...'

    print *, 'Final address is', loc(argument)

  end program trial
```

the output is:

```
Trial program starts
Initial address is            4351590240
In constructor address is:        140734743834256
Destructor of my_type object with address: 4351590240
Destructor of my_type object with address: 140734743834256
Address afer constructor is called is      4351590240     
doing some work...
finishing program...
Final address is            4351590240
```

So it seems that constructed object is destructed as soon as its construction ends rather than at the end of the program.
Any ideas what's wrong?
Above code was compiled with ifort 14.0.0,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong (bar apparent (?) use of fixed form source continuation with Fortran 2003 code in 2013).

The first "destructor" call is to finalize the left hand side of the assignment statement.

The second call is to finalize the function result (conceptually after the value of that result has been used in the expression and transferred to the left hand side of the assignment).

Entities existing immediately prior to termination of the program (here by execution of the end program statement) are not finalized.

Comment: Ok, I get the constructor returns object by value, hence it also calls a destructor. But since destructor for `argument` isn't called at the end of the program, what about releasing memory for any allocatable members (or derived members) it might have? Will compiler take care of that?

Comment: Well, ok, I made a small example and seems that yes, it does.

Comment: Finalization and "automatic deallocation" are not the same thing, though there are common aspects and requirements in terms of execution sequence.  In both cases, there is a difference in behaviour for finalization and deallocation between the end of a program and end of a procedure or end of a BLOCK construct.

Comment: Also allocatables need not to be deallocated prior to termination of the program. AFAIK recent patch that enabled finalization in gfortran disabled automatic deallocation at the program end in order not to invoke finalization.

Comment: @IanH what about if you e.g. have pointers (like linked list) within the declared type `my_type`, the compiler will not deallocate automatically, and since the finalization routine is not executed at the termination of the program, what is the point with finalization in that case?