# Fortran: How to plug memory leak from un-deallocated pointer in linked list

Tags: oop, pointers, memory-leaks, linked-list, fortran

I have a doubly-linked list implemented in Fortran 2008 (GNU Fortran v4.9.2). The list behaves as expected in terms of being able to insert/delete/push/pop, but under heavy use there is a memory leak I believe is coming pointers that are not being deallocated.

Here is a minimum working case:

```
module c_DLLMod
  implicit none
  private

  type, public :: c_Node
    private
    type(c_Node), pointer :: Parent => null(), Child => null()
    integer, allocatable :: Val
  contains
    procedure :: GetVal => m_GetVal
    procedure :: SetVal => m_SetVal
  end type c_Node

  type, public :: c_DLL
    private
    type(c_Node), pointer :: Head => null(), Tail => null()
    integer :: Size
    logical :: IsReady = .false.
  contains
    procedure :: Front => m_Front
    procedure :: PushFront => m_PushFront
    procedure :: PopFront => m_PopFront
    procedure :: Delete => m_Delete
    procedure :: IsEmpty => m_IsEmpty
    procedure :: Free => m_Free
  end type c_DLL

  interface c_DLL
    module procedure m_NewDLL
  end interface c_DLL

contains

  !  Begin c_Node methods

  subroutine m_SetVal(N, Val)
    class(c_Node), intent(inout) :: N
    integer, intent(in) :: Val

    if (.not. allocated(N%Val)) allocate(N%Val)
    N%Val = Val
  end subroutine m_SetVal

  integer function m_GetVal(N) result(Val)
    class(c_Node), intent(in) :: N

    Val = N%Val
  end function m_GetVal

  !  End c_Node methods

  !  Begin c_DLL methods

!  Initialize linked list by setting initial size and ready status
  function m_NewDLL() result(L)
    type(c_DLL) :: L

    L%Size = 0

    L%IsReady = .true.
  end function m_NewDLL

!  Make sure that the head points to the first node and the tail to the last
  subroutine m_Listify(L)
    class(c_DLL), intent(inout) :: L

    do while(associated(L%Head%Parent))
      L%Head => L%Head%Parent
    end do

    do while(associated(L%Tail%Child))
      L%Tail => L%Tail%Child
    end do
  end subroutine m_Listify

!  Return the value stored in the front (head) node
  integer function m_Front(L) result(Val)
    class(c_DLL), intent(in) :: L

    Val = 0
    if (L%IsReady) Val = L%Head%GetVal()
  end function m_Front

!  Push new value to the front of the list
  subroutine m_PushFront(L, Val)
    class(c_DLL), intent(inout) :: L
    integer, intent(in) :: Val

    if (L%IsReady) then
      if (L%Size == 0) then
!        List is new or empty, so need to allocate the head node
!        and assign its value to Val
        if (.not. associated(L%Head)) then
          allocate(L%Head)
          L%Tail => L%Head ! List only has 1 value, so tail and head are same
        end if
        call L%Head%SetVal(Val)
      else
!        List is not empty, so make sure head and tail point to right
!        nodes, then allocate new node in front of the head and assign
!        Val to it.
        call m_Listify(L)
        allocate(L%Head%Parent)
        call L%Head%Parent%SetVal(Val)
        L%Head%Parent%Child => L%Head ! Give the new head its child node
        nullify(L%Head%Parent%Parent) ! Tell new head that it is in fact the head (i.e. no parent node)
        L%Head => L%Head%Parent ! Set head pointer to the new head
      end if
      L%Size = L%Size + 1
    end if
  end subroutine m_PushFront

!  Remove the head node from the list
  subroutine m_PopFront(L)
    class(c_DLL), intent(inout) :: L

    if (L%IsReady .and. L%Size > 0) then
      if (associated(L%Head%Child)) then
!        List has more than 1 value, so need to point head to the
!        new head after popping
        L%Head => L%Head%Child
        call m_Delete(L, L%Head%Parent) ! Head%Parent is actually the head until it's deleted
      else
!        List has only 1 element, so can simply delete it
        call m_Delete(L, L%Head)
      end if
    end if
  end subroutine m_PopFront

!  Remove a node N from the list, maintaining connectivity in the list
  subroutine m_Delete(L, N)
    class(c_DLL), intent(inout) :: L
    type(c_Node), pointer, intent(inout) :: N

    if (L%IsReady .and. L%Size >= 1) then
      deallocate(N%Val) ! Deallocate the integer Val of the node to be deleted (N)
      if (associated(N%Parent)) then
        if (associated(N%Child)) then
!          N has both parent and child nodes, so need to point parent to child
!          and child to parent so that the list stays connected
          N%Child%Parent => N%Parent
          N%Parent%Child => N%Child
        else
!          N has only parent node, so the parent's child pointer will now become null,
!          so that the parent know's it's the new tail of the list
          nullify(N%Parent%Child)
        end if
      else
        if (associated(N%Child)) then
!          N has only child node, so the child's parent pointer will now become null,
!          so that the child know's it's the new head of the list
          nullify(N%Child%Parent)
        end if
      end if

!      At this point I'm done with N, and N was allocated earlier by
!      either the m_NewDLL function or inside a call to m_PushFront,
!      but if I try to deallocate then it throws a runtime error that
!      N isn't allocated and cannot be deallocated.
!      deallocate(N)
      nullify(N)
      L%Size = L%Size - 1
    end if
  end subroutine m_Delete

!  Check if list is empty
  logical function m_IsEmpty(L)
    class(c_DLL), intent(in) :: L

    m_IsEmpty = (L%Size == 0)
  end function m_IsEmpty

!  Delete all elements of the list, starting with the head node
  subroutine m_Free(L)
    class(c_DLL), intent(inout) :: L

    type(c_Node), pointer :: Cur

    if (L%IsReady .and. L%Size > 0) then
      Cur => L%Head
      do while(associated(Cur%Child))
        Cur => Cur%Child
        call m_Delete(L, Cur%Parent)
      end do
      call m_Delete(L, Cur)
      L%Size = 0
      L%IsReady = .false.
    end if
  end subroutine m_Free

end module c_DLLMod

!  Simple test program that pushs array values to a list
!  and then pops them off the front of the list.
!  This behavior is that of a stack, so the order
!  of array elements is reversed in the process of
!  pushing/popping.
program main
  use c_DLLMod
  implicit none
  type(c_DLL) :: List
  integer, dimension(10) :: A
  integer :: i, j

!  When IsDebug is true, the test will execute 10 million times, and
!  the program's memory cost will go to ~2.5GB.
!  When IsDebug is false, the test will execute once, and will output
!  values along the way so that you can see the list is
!  performing as expected.
  logical :: IsDebug = .true.

  A = (/ 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9 /)

  write(*,*) 'Starting test'

  List = c_DLL()
  do j = 1, 10000000
    if (IsDebug) write(*,*) 'populate list'
    do i = 1, 10
      call List%PushFront(A(i))
      if (IsDebug) write(*,*) List%Front()
    end do

    if (IsDebug) write(*,*) 'empty list'
    do while(.not. List%IsEmpty())
      if (IsDebug) write(*,*) List%Front()
      call List%PopFront
    end do
    if (IsDebug) stop
  end do

  write(*,*) 'Finished'

  call List%Free
end program main
```

Switch the value of `IsDebug` to toggle the short/long versions of the test.

Each `c_Node` has a integer pointer that is allocated before a value is stored, and deallocated in `m_Delete()` when the node is no longer required. On line 160 (`deallocate(N)` in `m_Delete()`) the node being deleted should be deallocated, but this line throws a runtime error stating that the node is not allocated and therefore is unable to be deallocated. When this line is commented out, the list works, but if the full test is run then the program will take ~2.5GB of memory, and I think the leak is due to these nodes not being deallocated when they’re deleted, resulting in millions of allocated pointers.

I’ve commented the code that, hopefully, you all can see what’s going on. I must be making a fundamental mistake somewhere with how I’ve implemented this linked list, but a similar implementation in C++ works just fine.

**What am I doing wrong that keeps a deleted node from being able to be deallocated?** Or is that actually the problem here?

Thanks,

Tim

P.S. On a side note, I'm not entirely sure when to use `nullify(pointer)` vs `pointer => null()`. Could you comment on my use of each please?

Comment: `Nullify(ptr)` and `ptr => null()` are completely equivalent if used as an executable statement. BTW we normally do not use "Thanks", "Regards" and signatures here. You have your signature below your post with your picture. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: BTW, if you use Fortran 2008,  finalization could be quite handy for you. It is not complete in gfortran 4.9, but i might cover your cases.

Comment: @VladimirF, I played around with `final` procedures before, expecting the same behavior as a destructor method in C++, but experienced the behavior talked about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485666/fortan-final-routine-calls-itself-before-variable-goes-out-of-scope). The `final` procedure would be called as soon as the derived type was used, and the only way I could get the program to behave as I desired was to manually call a subroutine to free the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to find the bug (after a short check with valgrind) is this piece:

```
!      At this point I'm done with N, and N was allocated earlier by
!      either the m_NewDLL function or inside a call to m_PushFront,
!      but if I try to deallocate then it throws a runtime error that
!      N isn't allocated and cannot be deallocated.
!     deallocate(N)
```

You **really** should deallocate `N`. The fact that it is null at this point means something is wrong!

The error is here:

```
       if (associated(N%Child)) then
!          N has only child node, so the child's parent pointer will now become null,
!          so that the child know's it's the new head of the list
           nullify(N%Child%Parent)
```

You are just now nullifying the `N` in fact, because what you passed to `m_Delete` was

```
call m_Delete(L, L%Head%Parent)
```

so that `N` is `L%Head%Parent` and `N%Child` is `L%Head` and its `Parent` is `N`. At least if I understand your code right.

Anyway, if I uncomment the deallocate and comment this nullify, it works nicely:

```
==3347== 
==3347== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3347==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3347==   total heap usage: 41 allocs, 41 frees, 12,271 bytes allocated
==3347== 
==3347== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3347== 
==3347== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3347== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

As IanH points out in his comment, there is also another issue. You are passing the same entity as an actual argument to `m_delete` two times in two separate arguments in this call:

```
call m_Delete(L, L%Head)
```

`L%Head` is part of L and you change the association status of `L%Head` through the second argument, but also the value of other parts of L through the first argument. This is not allowed. The shortest way to resolve this is to add the `target` attribute to the first dummy argument of `m_Delete` along paragraph 12.5.2.13p1(3b) of the Fortran 2008 standard. All restrictions are in section 12.5.2.13 of F2008.

Comment: @IanH I don't know the rules well when pointer arguments are around. Could you explain this situation? I think `L` is used only for getting `IsReady` and `Size`.

Comment: Right, good point, the pointer association status of `%Head` is changed there through a different dummy argument. I have ovelooked that.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast and correct answer @VladimirF! But I'm confused. `N%Child%Parent` is a pointer of type `c_Node` that is a member of the node pointed to by `N%Child`. I get that `N%Child%Parent` is actually pointing at `N`, but shouldn't the `nullify()` be acting to disassociate the `Parent` pointer of the node pointed to by `N%Child`, rather then finding it's way back to `N` and nullifying `N`? That is to say if `A`  points to `B` and both `A` and `B` are pointers, then nullifying `A` should not also nullify `B` right?

Comment: And @VladimirF, by removing the `nullify()`s from the code, does this not leave `N%Parent%Child` or `N%Child%Parent` in an undefined pointer state? Since my goal was not to nullify `N`, but to make sure that the nodes that once pointed to `N` have such pointers put into a correct state.

Comment: No, the problem was you are nullifying what you should be deallocating first. You are nullifying `N` after the deallocation anyway and `N` is that thing you nullified too early before. It is all caused by the fact that you pass `L%Head%Parent` to `m_Delete()`.